# Dropdown Selection from Component is not working

Tags: angular

In Angular 2 I'm going to select an item on dropdown by after emitting an event. for this, I'm using the select operator like as follow. but the selection does not work for the following equal comparison

```
<select id="inputState" class="form-control" formControlName="clientId">
    <option value="">--Select a Client --</option>
    <option *ngFor="let client of clientDataList" [value]="client.id" [selected]="client.id == 2">{{client.name}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: Are you sure `client.id` is a number?

Comment: Is it `multiselect`>

Comment: and how this `clientDataList` looks like?

Comment: @Chrillerwoodz it is comming from an objeck like this
{id: 0, name: "d", code: "CL-232", address: {…}}

Comment: no is not multiselect

Comment: Please add sample data and expected output in the question!